# Exception when running main window swing

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

So im doing kind of a wallapop project for college but simplified. I've already done two windows, without any functionality at all, just the design. I tried to make a login button redirect to another window where you get a login form, but when i execute the program it only says build success and it shows all this long exception:`

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at VentanaInicial.initComponents(VentanaInicial.java:39)
    at VentanaInicial.<init>(VentanaInicial.java:17)
    at VentanaInicial$2.run(VentanaInicial.java:148)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

This thing happens in both windows when i execute them, i would appreciate any help. Im using Netbeans in case it helps. Here's the main window code:

```
public class VentanaInicial extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form VentanaInicial
     */
    public VentanaInicial() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/jp.png"))); // NOI18N

        jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/botonIniSes1.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setBorderPainted(false);
        jButton1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        jButton1.setFocusPainted(false);
        jButton1.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/botonIniSes2.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/botonRegistrar1.png"))); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setBorderPainted(false);
        jButton2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        jButton2.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        jButton2.setFocusPainted(false);
        jButton2.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/botonRegistrar2.png"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft YaHei Light", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Vende tus productos, ahora sin comisiones!");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(191, 191, 191)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 57, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGap(53, 53, 53))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addComponent(jButton1))
                        .addGap(176, 176, 176))))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(78, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        InicioSesion ini = new InicioSesion();
        ini.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);   
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VentanaInicial.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VentanaInicial.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VentanaInicial.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VentanaInicial.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new VentanaInicial().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: As i wrote behind, i identified the problem, it was the images, when i delete them from the program it works fine, but i need to put images on it so i dont know how to solve this.

Comment: Did you understand what is an `NPE`? Did you wonder why NPEs take place when you add the images?

Comment: May it be because the program doesnt find the image so it points to null?

Comment: Take a look at [Loading image resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/loading-image-resource).